# Random sample without repetition but probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am somehow missing a function in python which is a combination of two I know.
I have a list of numbers and probabilities for those and want to chose n of them, without repetition.

random.sample can chose from a list without repetition, but does not allow probabilities:

```
l = [5,124,6,2,7,1]
sample(l,k=5)
```

On the other hand, choices allows me to use weights, but uses repetition:

```
choices(l,k=2,weights=[0.5,0.25,0.25,0.125,0,0.125])
```

Is there any chance how do to that in combination?
Until now I run a while-loop doing choices so often until the number of uniquely chosen elements becomes k. But this is quite inefficient, in particular of one element has big probability.

Comment: You should not be concerned about "efficiency" of random sampling unless you have measured your program's running time and found the running time to be unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) works. Use:

```
import numpy as np

l = [5,124,6,2,7,1]
weights=[0.5,0.25,0.25,0.125,0,0.125]
weights = [w/sum(weights) for w in weights]
np.random.choice(l, size=5, replace=False, p=weights)
```

Edited to make probabilities sum to 1

Comment: This is great, thank you. Interesting that np choice wants normalisation while the standard one does not care